# EF Code First Error Message expression could not be evaluated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a subscription table, and at first we had a direct mapping with a class named Subscription. We changed that mapping, so that now the SubscriptionDto class maps to the subscription table.

The changes I have made to the DatabaseContext class:

[image: ChangesDatabaseContext]

For the CompanyRepresentation, there's this piece of configuration in the DatabaseContext:

[image: DbConCompRep]

The SubscriptionDto class is identical to the Subscription class, the only thing the Subscription class doesn't have is the virtual keyword on every collection property. It looks like this:

[image: SubscriptionsDto]

In the code it used the Subscription class to the database and from the database, but since it got replaced with the SubscriptionDto class, a conversion needs to be done. This is done in the repository class SubscriptionsInSql:

[image: SubscriptionsInSql]

The code that does the conversion from SubscriptionDto to Subscription throws an error when trying to assign subscriptionDto.CompanyRepresentation to CompanyRepresentation: "There's already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first".

If I look at what is retrieved in the ForAccountWith method, I see that there's an exception as well:

[image: ErrorMessageOnEvaluation]

I've tried many things, like removing the virtual keywords, data annotations, etc., but I can't seem to figure the thing out that makes this work. Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: first: why do you return an IList that will always be populated by 0 or 1 Subscription. Second: have you tried `var v  = repo.Find(x => id == sid).FirstOrDefault(); return CreateSubscription(v);`

Comment: @tschmit007 The First question... Well, I have no good answer for that. The Second thing; unfortunately, it doesn't work; when I look in v it gives me the same "The runtime has refused to evaluate the expression at this time." exception

Comment: @tschmit007 The First question; an account can have multiple subscriptions.

Comment: While this doesn't solve your problem.  You should be careful about your naming.  The term DTO means "Data Transfer Object" and refers to objects used as a middleman between an entity and something else.  A DTO is never an entity itself, but you've made a DTO an entity in your model, and that's poor design.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) theoretically only retrieve one entity.

please try :

```
List<Subscription> res = new List<Subscription>();
foreach (SubscriptionDto dto in repository.Where(x => x.AccountId == accountId)) {
    res.Add(CreateSubscription(dto));
}

return res;
```

Comment: This did not work out. We've decided to forgo the whole thing and try another approach. Thanks for your time for replying.

Answer (score 1):

The error "There's already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" typically means you have not enabled Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) in your connection string.

For instance:

```
Data Source=<db>;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

However, looking at your code, I think you have misinterpreted your requirements.  It seems like you are trying to replace Subscription with SubscriptionDto, but that's not the way DTO patterns typically work.  Almost certainly what is required is that you translate Subscription to SubscriptionDto in your repository layer.  Dto's are Data Transfer Objects and are used as intermediaries between your data layer and you business or other layers.  This decouples your data layer from your other layers.

Comment: Yes, I haven't got the correct implementation of DTO's in the code. We've decided to forgo the whole thing and try another approach. Thanks for your time for replying.